# How do I load an HTML file into Rstudio in the rmd format?

Tags: r

I am trying to load this (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/356229_cec311f7fea94ce9ac960ce9dc095b9c.html) into rstudio so I can edit it.  I'm a beginner and really don't know where to start.  Thank you.

Comment: The page you are trying to load into RStudio is an html file, not an Rmd file. This page looks as though it was _knitted from_ an Rmd file, and it's _talking about_ Rmd files, but it is _not itself_ an Rmd file. It is not possible in general to reverse-engineer the knitting process. You could instead try following the instructions in the html to recreate its examples, or you could try to find the Rmd file that was the source code for this html. You _can_ open html files in RStudio and tinker with them, but that is quite separate from dealing with Rmd files, and isn't what you want to do here.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand completely.  Thank you for your help, I was unclear on the directions.